# Stretch a TextInput to WidgetBox width

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to stretch the width several TextInput Widgets in bokeh to the width of the widget box or VBox containing the TextInput Widgets and other widgets. My current result looks like this:

[image]

I already tried to use the keyword `sizing_mode='stretch_both'` at different places with no effect.

Is it somehow possible to change the width of TextInput? Preferable would be using `sizing_mode` for a responsive layout.

** Edit: Another example **

An example showing the same effect from the bokeh resources is the movie example: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/movies
If I use sizing_mode = 'scale_width' (line 107) it becomes quite obvious, everything stretches, except the TextInput:

[image]

Comment: On https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!search/TextInput/bokeh/XssvnyMiDy0/m4xWypCxBwAJ it is stated that this is only possible by using css. Is this still true? If yes hints on "how" would be appreciated.

Comment: a workaround is described [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6427)